# Iterate through records in multiple Models

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have  been trying to display data from four tables. I have `IEnumerable<>` on my view and I've also created a class `SingleModel` that holds all three classes together.The aim of this is to display records as per the `Telephone` that acts as the parameter. But I keep getting an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

on this line of code

```
join ct in x3 on st.ID equals ct.ID into table2
```

on the controller

The Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        List<SingleView> x1 = db.SingleViews.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();
        List<SingleViewM> x2 = db.SingleViewMs.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();
        List<SingleViewWst> x3 = db.SingleViewWsts.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();
        List<PensionsView> x4 = db.PensionsViews.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();

        var multipletables = from c in x1
                             join st in x2 on c.ID equals st.ID into table1
                             from st in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join ct in x3 on st.ID equals ct.ID into table2
                             from ct in table2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new SingleModel { USSD = c, Mombasa = st, Western = ct };

        return View(multipletables);
    }
```

The Model:

```
public class SingleModel
{
    public SingleView USSD { get; set; }
    public SingleViewM Mombasa { get; set; }
    public SingleViewWst Western { get; set; }
    public PensionsView PensionsViews{ get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```
    @model  IEnumerable<MinetSingleView.Models.SingleModel>


                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td>@item.USSD.InsurerName</td>
                                <td>@item.USSD.PolicyType</td>
                                <td>@item.USSD.RenewalDate</td>
                                <td>@item.USSD.PolicyNo</td>
                                <td>@item.USSD.Telephone</td>
                                <td>@item.USSD.Status</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>

                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Insurance</th>
                            <th>Policy Type</th>
                            <th>Renewal Date</th>
                            <th>Policy Number</th>
                            <th>Telephone</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td>@item.Mombasa.InsurerName</td>
                                <td>@item.Mombasa.PolicyType</td>
                                <td>@item.Mombasa.RenewalDate</td>
                                <td>@item.Mombasa.PolicyNo</td>
                                <td>@item.Mombasa.Telephone</td>
                                <td>@item.Mombasa.Status</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the `left join` means that if there is no matching record in the second table then all those values are `null` (different from a normal `join` that it will not return the record from the left table).You might have the `st` equals `null` for that record so you have to check it

Try this:

```
   public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        List<SingleView> x1 = db.SingleViews.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();
        List<SingleViewM> x2 = db.SingleViewMs.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();
        List<SingleViewWst> x3 = db.SingleViewWsts.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();
        List<PensionsView> x4 = db.PensionsViews.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList();

        var multipletables = from c in x1
                             join st in x2 on c.ID equals st.ID into table1
                             from st in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join ct in x3 on st?.ID equals ct?.ID into table2
                             from ct in table2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new SingleModel { USSD = c, Mombasa = st, Western = ct };

        return View(multipletables);
    }
```

Also see use of `?.` in your `select new`

Comment: this code only works (displays records) from x1 on the view only. The rest of the tables (x2,x3,x4) result in the same initial error

Comment: Can you use `?` for all join

Comment: i have tried that but unfortunately, it doesn't display records from the other tables, and when i search using an id related to x1 it leads to the initial error

Comment: alternatively, is there a way I can replace the lines List<SingleView> x1 = db.SingleViews.Where(a => a.Telephone == id).ToList(); etc with a single line of TableModel